# Priority of custom queue compared to Global queue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have created a concurrent custom queue in iOS to run few of the threads parallel. What is the impact of this queue on dispatch global queue? Will this block operations on global dispatch queue till it gets completed? Can we run specific set of threads on global dispatch queue to run concurrently with high priority?

When i use global dispatch queue, i observed it is using one core at a time. How can i optimize global dispatch queue to use multi cores?

Comment: If question is not clear, help me to improve it. I am trying to use global_dispatch_queue effectively with multicores

Comment: any answers for this?